# Android: Audio Track (Stream-Mode) cuts between write

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, audiotrack

My main goal is to be able to stream audio from one device to another device in the LAN. I plan doing this by reading the mp3-file into a byte[] (which I already got working) and send it as udp-packet to the 2nd device and play it there (I'm telling you this in case this is already the wrong approach). I'm currently stuck with playing my byte-Arrays. I read my file with the `decoder(path, startMs, durationMs)` function from mp3. At the moment I am able to hear the audio but after every tick (which are the portions in which I read the file) I hear a nothing for some ms, which leads to a bad listening expierence. I thought this has to do with the Buffer-Size and tried playing around a bit with it, but this didn't really change something, as well as adding `AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING`. I also thought about putting every for()-loop in a different thread, but this doesn't work at all (which makes sense). I also already tried reading the file first and putting my byte[] in an Arraylist as this might be an issue cause by slow-file-reading, but still the same experience. It might also help to know that `Log.e("DEBUG", "Length " + data.length);` is only shown every tick, which means writing also only happens every tick (which proably is the issue). How can I get rid of these empty parts in my song?

Here is my code executed when you click the button:

```
song.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Thread thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                int tick = 1000;
                                int max = 9000;
                                int sampleRate = 44100;
                                int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate*4, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                                byte[] data = decode(path, 0, tick);
                                AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize,
                                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
                                track.play();
                                track.write(data, 0, data.length);
                                Log.e("DEBUG", "Length " + data.length);
                                for(int i = tick; i < max; i+=tick) {
                                    data = decode(path, i, tick);
                                    track.write(data, 0, data.length);
                                    Log.e("DEBUG", "Length " + data.length);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    thrd.start();
                }
            });
```

My `decode()`-function (based on [this tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/)) with JLayer 1.0.1:

```
public static byte[] decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

        float totalMs = 0;
        boolean seeking = true;

        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 8 * 1024);
        try {
            Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
            Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

            boolean done = false;
            while (! done) {
                Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
                if (frameHeader == null) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

                    if (totalMs >= startMs) {
                        seeking = false;
                    }

                    if (!seeking) {
                        SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);

                        if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100
                                || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
                            Log.w("ERROR", "mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported");
                        }

                        short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                        for (short s : pcm) {
                            outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                            outStream.write((s >> 8) & 0xff);
                        }
                    }

                    if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
                bitstream.closeFrame();
            }
        } catch (BitstreamException e) {
            throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            Log.w("ERROR", "Decoder error", e);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return outStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

I don't think the decode-function is the problem, as the byte[] returned seems to be quite good. Maybe the reading process could be optimized as later, when I really stream the audio and read always about 10ms parts, always opening and closing the file might be an issue.

Comment: Please add the implementation of your `decode()` function.

Comment: @greeble31 thanks for your feedback, decode() is included now!

Comment: Take note of which `AudioTrack` constructor you're using; your last parameter is actually a mismatch. All your writes have been blocking. And they need to be, in order for the threading scheme you've chosen to work. You are assuming that `write()` returns exactly the number of bytes that was requested, so you don't want to have any "short writes".

Comment: OK, so you are not streaming anything yet -- you're just trying to make an .mp3 player, at this point. Your code should work, but `decode()` needs to consistently execute faster than, oh, about 100ms (on most devices), or else the internal `AudioTrack` buffer will starve. Do you think that's the case?

Comment: I don't think the reading is the problem as I already tried reading the file first and putting it into an ArrayList<bytes[]> before even playing the track and reading from this list afterwards. I did not notice any difference, still had these time-spans with no audio playing. And I see there might be an issue with the non-blocking part, seems to be part of the write() method [ https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MidiScope/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/common/midi/synth/SimpleAudioOutput.java ]

Comment: Okay, now I removed the AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING from the the AudioTrack() and added it to the end of the write() function, which leads to nearly no audio played (I'm not sure, I hear some ms of playback, but at least much less than the int tick. But now all the Log.e("DEBUG", "Length " + data.length); are executed really fast, so again reading does not seem to be a problem. But this still is no solution as it seems like the audio is written much faster now, but does maybe override itself (but the length of int tick should at least be played once?).

Comment: I would respectfully disagree. Since you tested this once by pre-loading all the data into RAM (`ArrayLists`), the `decode()` function is now the only remaining culprit. I could think of several easy ways to test that theory, but perhaps you've already looked at the waveform, and made sure it goes all the way to each end of each `byte[]` array?

Comment: By the way, you need your writes to be blocking, not non-blocking. That's what I meant by my second comment.

Comment: First, thanks for the Blocking, changed it, and I'm at least hearing it again but with the gaps again too. I'm not sure what to do with your first comment. How am I supposed to look at the waveform? Maybe you could suggest me some code and I can try it, would help me really much. And thanks for all your help till now!

Comment: Well, you could just dump the contents of the byte array, not the whole thing but maybe the first 100 samples and the last 100 samples, and make sure the data is "wavey". You should probably convert them to `shorts` first.

Comment: Or, each time you get a result back from `decode()`, you can turn it into a square wave by replacing the contents of the array with this pattern, repeated end-to-end, to cover the entire array: `[ 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. That should produced a continuous, high-pitched tone, without any gaps. If the gaps are still there after you turn the audio into a 9-second long square wave, then I am certainly in the wrong. You could just do it with a `for` loop: `if( ((i / 16) % 2) == 0 ) data[i] = 127; else data[i] = 0;`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I tried what you wrote. I overwrote the byte[] before returning it (but still did all the I/O Stuff the function had before) and now the sound seems to be continuous. So the problems seems to be the byte[] I recieve from my decode() function, right? Do you have an idea how to fix it? Maybe even something which not only supports mp3, but I'd already be fine with mp3 at this moment.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really understand the decode function, but maybe it has something to do with the ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024); since my lengths of arrays are no always dividable by 1024 (and the also seem not always to have the same length, also they cover the same time-length)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186947/discussion-between-greeble31-and-blocklab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this turned out to be: You were using the `decode()` function in a way for which it wasn't specifically designed. Even though it appears `decode()` will let you decode any portion of the .mp3 stream in a random-access way, in practice the first few ms of the returned audio are *always silence*, whether you're starting at the beginning of the song, or in the middle. This silence was causing the "gaps". Apparently the `decode()` function was intended more for *re-starting* play at a random location, for instance due to a user "seek".

`decode()` behaves that way because, in order to decode the Nth block of compressed data, the decoder needs both block N-1 *and* block N. The decompressed data that corresponds to block N will be good, but the data for block N-1 will have this "fade in" sound. This is a general feature of .mp3 decoders, and I know it happens for AAC as well. Meanwhile, decoding block N+1, N+2, N+3, etc., is no problem, because in each case, the decoder already has the previous block.

One solution is to change the `decode()` function:

```
private Decoder decoder;
private float totalMs;
private Bitstream bitstream;
private InputStream inputStream;

//call this once, when it is time to start a new song:
private void startNewSong(String path) throws IOException
{
    decoder = new Decoder();
    totalMs = 0;
    File file = new File(path);
    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 8 * 1024);
    bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
}

private byte[] decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs)
        throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);


    try {
        boolean done = false;
        while (! done) {
            Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
            if (frameHeader == null) {
                done = true;
                inputStream.close();   //Note this change. Now, the song is done. You can also clean up the decoder here.
            } else {
                totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();

                SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);

                if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100
                        || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
                    Log.w("ERROR", "mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported");
                }

                short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
                for (short s : pcm) {
                    outStream.write(s & 0xff);
                    outStream.write((s >> 8) & 0xff);
                }

                if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            bitstream.closeFrame();
        }
    } catch (BitstreamException e) {
        throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        Log.w("ERROR", "Decoder error", e);
    }
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}
```

That code is a bit rough & ready, and it could use some improvement. But the general approach is, instead of random access, `decode()` uses an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to decode a little more of the song each time; read a little bit more of the file, and send a few more chunks to the decoder. Because the decoder (and `bitstream`) state is preserved between each call to `decode()`, there is no need to go hunting for block N-1.

**UDP and Streaming**

The validity of your UDP approach depends on a lot of things. You may want to look for other questions that address that in particular. UDP is convenient for broadcasting to multiple devices on a given subnet, but it will not help you ensure packets are received in order, or at all. You may want TCP instead. Also consider whether you want to transmit the encoded .mp3 blocks (those returned by `bitstream.readFrame()`), or blocks of decompressed audio. Also think about how you will deal with network latency, dropped connections, and buffering. There are many difficult design decisions to make here, and each choice has pros and cons. Good luck.